# Error in uuid4r gem installation in linux

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am getting this error

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/kiwitech/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-opt-include=/usr/local/opt/ossp-uuid/include --with-opt-lib=/home/kiwitech/Documents/ossp-uuid
checking for uuid_export() in -luuid... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/kiwitech/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
    --with-uuidlib
    --without-uuidlib
OSSP uuid library 'uuid' required -- not found.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/kiwitech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/uuid4r-0.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/kiwitech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/uuid4r-0.2.0/gem_make.out
```

Please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `libossp-uuid` and it's dev headers.

Probably something like:

```
sudo apt-get install libossp-uuid-dev
```

And then the gem installs.

Are you sure you need to use that gem anyway? In ruby 1.9+ there's already the module [SecureRandom](http://apidock.com/ruby/SecureRandom/uuid/class) in standard library which provides UUID and also lots of pure ruby gems like [uuidtools](https://rubygems.org/gems/uuidtools) and [uuid](https://rubygems.org/gems/uuid). If you need to parse the UUID's, there's [ruby-uuid](https://github.com/shyouhei/ruby-uuid).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running OS X Yosemite do the following:

gem install uuid

brew install ossp-uuid

(You need to have brew already installed.  If you don't you can get it from here: http://brew.sh)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `rvm`, check that your session state is correct. If you `cd` around a lot, `reset` your terminal, or your environment variables get corrupted, you can end up with your commands trying to work with the system Ruby. A quick way to reset rvm-related stuff is just doing `cd .` in a project directory.

```
$ cd .
$ gem install uuid
```